# Не рассылаются метки mpls между маршрутизаторами

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, vpn, протоколы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Настраиваю сеть mpls в связке с bgp на microtik. Настроил bgp между несколькими AS, корректно работает. Далле начал настраивать mpls в области 15011. Для этого необходимо настроить LDP настроил, но метки рассылаются только между R2 и R3 остальные вообще никак, хотя настройки одинаковые. В чём может быть проблема?